# Swift 2 migration error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context "

Tags: swift, swift2

After running the Swift 2 migration I got this error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

for this line:

```
 var interestItems = [String, NSNumber, Bool]()
```

Comment: Surely you mean `[(String, NSNumber, Bool)]` - it's not just the compiler that doesn't know what to make of your expression...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 1.2 the compiler automatically infers the type `[(String, NSNumber, Bool)]` (array of tuples) from `[String, NSNumber, Bool]`.

It does not anymore since Swift 2, after the migration you have to declare the tuple explicitly:

```
var interestItems = [(String, NSNumber, Bool)]()
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric D. That is exactly what I am looking for. Our code base is extensive and we have  a ton of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to make this an array of "tuples" consisting of `String`, `NSNumber`, and `Bool`, you'd do something like:

```
var interestItems = [(String, NSNumber, Bool)]()

interestItems.append(("foo", 42, true))
interestItems.append(("bar", -1, true))
```

That results in an array of two items, each which is a tuple consisting of a `String`, a `NSNumber`, and a `Bool`.

On the other hand, if you meant to make this an array of items that may be `String`, `NSNumber`, or `Bool`, you'd have to just declare it as an array of `AnyObject`:

```
var interestItems = [AnyObject]()

interestItems.append("foo")
interestItems.append(42)
interestItems.append(true)
```

That is an array with three items.

I assume you meant the former, but these are a few approaches.